# How do I declare a new string the same length of a known const string?

Tags: c++, string, assignment-operator

I've been using:

```
string letters = THESAMELENGTH; // Assign for allocation purposes.
```

Reason being, if I:

```
string letters[THESAMELENGTH.length()];
```

I get a non constant expression complaint.

But if I:

```
string letters[12];
```

I'm at risk of needing to change every instance if the guide const string changes size.

But it seems foolish to assign a string when I won't use those entries, I only want my newly assigned string to be the same length as the previously assigned const string, then fill with different values.

How do you recommend I do this gracefully and safely?

Comment: `string letters[12]`, does not mean a string of length 12.  It is an array containing 12 strings.

Comment: s=strdup(existing); will duplicate a string, which can be deleted with free(s);

Comment: Thanks Vaughn, that distinction is crucial and I hadn't seen it. I was thinking of string as a char array.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport: A single string is indeed an array of characters and can be accessed as such (e.g. `char letter = word[letter_index];`). Just note that an array of `char` and an array of `string` are different b/c they're different types. The fact that it's convenient to build `string`s out of `char` types is just that, a practical convenience.

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and accept answers that were useful to you. That's how we say "thank you" around here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I only want my newly assigned string to be the same length as the previously assigned const string, then fill with different values.

Part of the reason the `string` class/type exists is so you don't have to worry about trying to manage its length. (The problem with arrays of `char`.)

If you have a `const std::string tmp` then you can't just assign anything to it after it has already been initialized. E.g.:

```
const std::string tmp = "A value";  // initialization
tmp = "Another value";              // compile error
```

> How do you recommend I do this gracefully and safely?

If you really want to keep strings to a specific size, regardless of their contents, you could always `resize` your `string` variables. For example:

```
// in some constants.h file
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 16;

// in other files
#include "constants.h"
// ...
std::string word = ... // some unknown string
word.resize(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

Now your `word` string will have a length/size of `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` and anything beyond the end gets truncated.

This example is from [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)

```
// resizing string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("I like to code in C");
  std::cout << str << '\n';

  unsigned sz = str.size();

  str.resize (sz+2,'+');
  std::cout << str << '\n';

  str.resize (14);
  std::cout << str << '\n';
  return 0;
}

// program output
I like to code in C
I like to code in C++
I like to code
```

You can't just ask a string *variable* for its length at compile-time. By definition, it's impossible to know the value of a *variable*, or the *state* of any given program for that matter, while it's not running. This question only makes sense at run-time.

Others have mentioned this, but there seems to be an issue with your understanding of `string letters[12];`. That gives you an array of `string` types, i.e. you get space for 12 full strings (e.g. words/sentences/etc), not just letters.

In other words, you could do:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i)
    letters[i] = "Hello, world!";
```

So your `letters` variable should be renamed to something more accurate (e.g. `words`).

If you really want letters (e.g. the full alphabet on a single string), you could do something like this:

```
// constants.h
const std::string ALPHABET_LC = "abc...z";
const std::string ALPHABET_UC = "ABC...Z";
const int LETTER_A = 0;
const int LETTER_B = 1;
// ...

// main.cpp, etc.
char a = ALPHABET_LC[LETTER_A];
char B = ALPHABET_UC[LETTER_B];
// ...
```

It all depends on what you need to do, but this might be a good alternative.

**Disclaimer:** Note that it's not really my recommendation that you do this. You should let `string`s manage their own length. For example, if the `string` value is actually shorter than your limit, you're causing your variable to use more space/memory than needed, and if it's longer, you're still truncating it. Neither side-effect is good, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. The problem is fairly simple. My reference string is const. So, I don't think of it as a variable because its size and contents are defined, and declared as const, at compile time. e.g. const string this = "this"; Later I want to declare a new string of the same length as 'this', but I will then write different contents to it. My question is, then, how should I declare this next string to be the same length as the first?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport: You could try `resize` on the new string using the `size` of the old one. For example `newstr.resize(oldstr.size());` after creating it. Note that you'd need to use `newstr.resize(oldstr.resize())` every time you assign something to it. However, doing this to strings does not really look "graceful" to me. It looks more like a "code smell" and I'd be suspicious if I were looking at that during a code review. Consider taking a few steps back to look at the problem from a distance and consider alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks_______________

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport: Moved (now deleted) comment to bottom of post as a 'disclaimer'

Answer (score 8):

You can

```
string letters(THESAMELENGTH.length(), ' '); // constructs the string with THESAMELENGTH.length() copies of character ' '
```

BTW: `string letters[12];` doesn't mean the same as you expected. It declares a raw array of `string` containing 12 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is understand the difference between a string length and an array dimension.

```
  std::string letters = "Hello";
```

creates a single `string` that contains the characters from `"Hello"`, and has length `5`.

In comparison

```
  std::string letters[5];
```

creates an array of five distinct default-constructed objects of type `std::string`.    It doesn't create a single string of 5 characters.   The reason for the non-constant complaint when doing

```
  std::string letters[THESAMELENGTH.length()];
```

is that construction of arrays in standard C++ is required to use a length known to the compiler, whereas the length of a `std::string` is determined at run time.

If you have a string, and what to create another string of the same length, you can do something like

```
  std::string another_string(letters.length(), 'A');
```

which will create a single string containing the required number of letters `'A'`.

It is largely pointless to do what you are seeking as a `std::string` can dynamically change its length anyway, as needed.    There is also nothing stopping a `std::string` from allocating more than it needs (e.g. to make provision for multiple increases in its length).

Comment: I understand the compiler needs a value it knows. Technically, the .length of the string Is known because it is declared as an assigned static const. A better explanation is the .length member function is Not executed at compile time. So when the compiler is looking for a value to assign, there isn't one. What would work is a way of establishing because the string length is constant at compile time you can substitute. In other words, a compile time .length function. 

It's pointless how? If I compile without any value for the array size, the program crashes.